# How to make sure document.write action takes place before body rendering finishes?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of JavaScript code which will be invoked asynchronously while the `<body>` is being rendered. Also I have a JavaScript file which will make use of this piece of code. This piece of code and the script to load the file are written in an external system. It is unpredictable that when this code will be inserted to page. I am unable to change the code in the JS file.

Now, the JS file contains document.write method to create an image. But, this method is not recommended since it is impossible to predict when the write action will take place. For example, if the it runs after the body rendering finishes and after the DOM is loaded, the page content will be entirely rewritten. 
I want to make sure that the above worst situation should not take place. How to do this ?

Comment: If your code is running asynchronously then you **cannot** guarantee it will execute before the DOM has loaded.

Comment: Agreed with Chris. You cannot guarantee it. Assuming you cannot change the document.write you could perhaps load the script in another document, a hidden frame for example, and then append the written text of the hidden document to your visibledocument. This would be a (dirty) work around.

Comment: @mrhobo, Or - you can simply overwrite `document.write` as described below ...

Answer (score 1):

Dont think you can be 100% certain. But you can use `document.body.innerHTML` instead of `document.write`

```
document.write('<img src="1.gif">');
```

will most likely reset the DOM, especially placed somewhere after `<body>`

```
document.body.innerHTML+='<img src="1.gif">';
```

will not, not even placed in a `window.onload` function.

---

**Now**, you say you cant change the code in the JS-file, but you can change `document.write` :

```
document.write = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML+=arguments[0];
}
```

If the JS calls `document.write` like this

```
document.write('<img src="1.gif">');
```

Then it is now actually `document.body.innerHTML+=arguments[0];` that is called, appending the `<img>` to the body.

Viola, you have overcomed the problem with `document.write` ...

Comment: But, the src for the image is dynamically created by appending some parameters.

Comment: The actual purpose of this image is to pass some values related to an online purchase.

Comment: Also, if I use this, all the other document.write methods in the page will also be replaced. Isn't it ?

Comment: @RaheebM, must see the code, otherwise it is pure guess - the above is only an example. Using arguments[] you can pass as many params as you want. document.write take only one param though -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write - a piece of html / markup

Comment: @RaheebM, yes - you should place the ducument.write replacement in <head> and then all call to document.write will go trough that replacement.